# How can I map Expression<Func<ContentDTO, bool>> to Expression<Func<Content,bool>>?

Tags: c#, mapping, expression-trees

I need to map between this 2 expressions

But I have complex logic for model mapping

My entities:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class ContentTranslation : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Content : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContentTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public FAQ Faq { get; set; }
    public Announcement Announcement { get; set; }
}

public class FAQ : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
}

public class Announcement : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValiUntil { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Content")]
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
}
```

My DTOs:

```
public class AnnouncementModel
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValiUntil { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JObject Content { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Language,TranslationDTO> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class FaqModel
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string MainTag { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create this mapping method?

I know that automapper has functionality to do such logic

But i have serialization (JObject property) so it is hard to use automapper

Will it be enough to map just two models in method(Content and ContentDto)?
_______UPDATE_________
I have two content types FAQ and Announcement
They are stored in different tables
In conbtent table there is ContentType acording to which I can select specific type of content and than serialize it to my JObject Content
Some code here

//get announcement model to store in jobject

```
private AnnouncementModel GetAnnouncement(int contentId, ContentType contentType)
    {
        var model = (from content in context.Contents
                     join announcement in context.Announcements on content.Id equals announcement.ContentId
                     where content.ContentType == ContentType.Announcement
                     && content.Id == contentId
                     select new AnnouncementModel()
                     {
                         ContentId = content.Id,
                         State = content.State,
                         Header = announcement.Header,
                         ValiUntil = announcement.ValiUntil
                     })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        return model;
    }
```

//get FAQ to store in JOBJect

```
  private FaqModel GetFaq(int contentId, ContentType contentType)
    {
        var model = (from content in context.Contents
                     join faq in context.FAQs on content.Id equals faq.ContentId
                     where content.ContentType == ContentType.FAQ
                     && content.Id == contentId
                     select new FaqModel()
                     {
                         ContentId = content.Id,
                         State = content.State,
                         MainTag = faq.Tag
                     })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        return model;
    }
```

//Convert type to store in Jobject

```
  private JObject GetContentAsync(ContentType contentType, int contentID)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() } };
        if (contentType == ContentType.FAQ)
        {
            var faq = GetFaq(contentID, contentType);
            return JObject.FromObject(faq, JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
        }
        if (contentType == ContentType.Announcement)
        {
            var annoncement = GetAnnouncement(contentID, contentType);
            return JObject.FromObject(annoncement, JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

//method to get content dictionary with translationDTO (conteint text translated) and Language as key

```
 private Tuple<Content, Dictionary<Language, TranslationDTO>> GetContentAndRelatedListOfTransactionById(int contentId)
    {
        var query =
            from content in context.Contents
            join translation in context.ContentTranslations on content.Id equals translation.ContentId
            where content.Id == contentId
            select new Tuple<Content, ContentTranslation>(content, translation);
        if (query != null)
            return new Tuple<Content, Dictionary<Language, TranslationDTO>>(query.FirstOrDefault()?.Item1,
                query.Select(p => p.Item2)?.ConvertToDictTranslations());
        else
            return null;//tuple is empty
    }
```

//And than I can crete model as here

```
public ContentDto MapToContentDTO(Content contentEntity)
    {
        var model = GetContentByIdWithTranslation(contentEntity.Id, contentEntity.ContentType);
        return model;
    }
```

I want to convert expression because I want to run in on my database table
But I get expression from view where DTOs and than want to convert it to my entities.

Comment: How is this related to Expressions and Func?

Comment: @Michael I think OP wants to turn some `Where` condition defined on DTO into one which could be run against DB.

Comment: To me, it looks like a simple mapping issue. @FairyFox5700, could you add more code to clarify your intention?

Comment: Side note regarding naming - methods, ending with `Async`, should return a `Task` and be declared with `async` keyword